# How to use scipy.integrate tplquad for a function that requires more than three (3) arguments

Tags: python, scipy

I'm building a python function that requires 6 (six) arguments, but returns a function of three variables. This last return I want to use in the scipy.integrate tplquad method.

Let 'Function1' be the first function said, so I define:

```
 def Function1(z,y,x,e,N,a):

    {code}

    return Function2
```

where Function2=f(z,y,x)

Then I need to use Function2 in another python function where I'm willing to use tplquad integration method, which it's said it requires "A Python function or method of at least three variables in the order (z, y, x).".

**So my question is how can I implement (if it is possible) a function with more than 3 arguments in the tplquad method, understanding that the three first arguments would be 'z,y,x'.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `tplquad(f,..., args=(e, N, a))`. Alternatively, pass in a lambda: `tplquad(lambda z, y, x: Function1(z,y,x, e, N, a), ...)`